# Rails assets precompile: Segmentation Fault + Ruby 1.9.3p392

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, asset-pipeline

I am deploying a simple rails application to a SUSE server with Capistrano.  While deploying when the below hook executes

```
after "deploy:update_code" do
  run <<-CMD
  cd #{current_release} &&
   RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace
  CMD
end
```

I get the below long error trace

```
        servers: ["application_server.com"]
    [application_server.com] executing command
*** [err :: application_server.com] ** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
*** [err :: application_server.com] ** Execute assets:precompile
*** [err :: application_server.com] /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby /opt/apps/myapplication.com/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=devutility RAILS_GROUPS=assets --trace
*** [err :: application_server.com] 
*** [err :: application_server.com] /opt/apps/myapplication.com/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.11.4/lib/v8/init.so:
*** [err :: application_server.com] [BUG]
*** [err :: application_server.com] Segmentation fault
*** [err :: application_server.com] ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386) [x86_64-linux]
*** [err :: application_server.com] -- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
*** [err :: application_server.com] c:0054
*** [err :: application_server.com] p:-4755442
*** [err :: application_server.com] s:0156 b:0156
*** [err :: application_server.com] l:000155
*** [err :: application_server.com] d:000155
*** [err :: application_server.com] TOP
*** [err :: application_server.com] 
*** [err :: application_server.com] c:0053
*** [err :: application_server.com] p:----
*** [err :: application_server.com] s:0154 b:0154
*** [err :: application_server.com] l:000153
*** [err :: application_server.com] d:000153
*** [err :: application_server.com] CFUNC
*** [err :: application_server.com] :require
*** [err :: application_server.com] 
*** [err :: application_server.com] c:0052
*** [err :: application_server.com] p:0035
*** [err :: application_server.com] s:0150 b:0150
*** [err :: application_server.com] l:000149
*** [err :: application_server.com] d:000149
*** [err :: application_server.com] TOP
```

Find complete trace here in my GIST https://gist.github.com/ankit8898/5051531 and the Gemfile is also present in it.

Any help will be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you remove therubyracer from your Gemfile and install [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) as your javascript runtime and don't worry about it again.

Therubyracer tends to be a lot of trouble and [consumes too much memory](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3x-asset-pipeline-cedar#troubleshooting).

Comment: Well i removed rubyracer from my Gemfile and just used Node.js.  and It worked!!! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try the previous version of therubyracer. In your Gemfile:

```
gem 'therubyracer', '0.11.3'
```